# How to create rules for work items in TFS 2018 and TFS 2019?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-devops-server-2019

I need to create rules for work items that will check for special characters in the fields. I need to ban all special characters like **`(@&*()^%$)`** etc. TFS supports this?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create rules for work items in TFS 2018 and TFS 2019?

I am afraid TFS 2018 and TFS 2019 do not yet support such fine rule restrictions.

According to the document [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops), we could to know the **conditions** and **actions** currently supported by the Workitem rule:

[image][image]

Obviously, we could not check all special characters for the fields at this moment, even if we use the conditions `The value of (...equals)`, since what we need is `The value of (...exclude)`.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.